# react-router v4: triggering a redirect programmatically (without having to render a <Redirect / >)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, react-router, react-dom

I'm currently switching my web app to react. The old one is located [here](http://vatcss.info/games/gotstats/).

What I'm trying to do is: when an user enter a player's username into the text field and submit, the app would redirect to the corresponding route (`/:username`), and the text field is cleared.

In the react version, this is what I'm doing currently:
https://github.com/AVAVT/g0tstats-react/blob/master/src/components/SideBar/SearchBox.js

```
submit(event){
    ...

    this.setState({
      redirect : true
    });

    ...
}
```

And

```
render(){
    ...
    {
          this.state.redirect && (
          <Redirect to={`/${this.state.username}`} push />
          )
    }
}
```

Which kinda work. But there are 2 things I don't like about it:

1. I'm rendering an element in order to redirect. It feels stupid and roundabout. It stinks of potential bug in the future.
2. I'm stuck with the text field not cleared. Because I if I set state.username to null the `<Redirect />` component will not redirect correctly. In fact I don't have any precise control over when the redirection occur (unless I do it in another roundabout way).

I have searched for alternative, but couldn't find one. `withRouter` doesn't work because `<SearchBox />` is not a `<Route />` and doesn't receive the history props.

So how can I say "redirect me to that place NOW" in react-router v4?

Comment: What about sending the routing props down from component that is rendering your `<SearchBox />`? Presumably if its not the one getting the props since its not directly being routed to, then its parent which is being routed to should.

Comment: `this.context.transitionTo(...)` is how you do programmatic redirect if I'm reading what your question correctly.

Comment: @promisified Actually no, the SearchBox's inside the sidebar, which is a siblings of the `<Route>s`

Comment: @1252748 if you can show me a working example I'd be much appreciated. I have tried many thing the past few days, `this.context` included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that shows when using the `withRouter` HOC, the routing props get injected to components even if they are not routed to.

Here is my `App.js`

```
    class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <BrowserRouter>
              <div>
                <Route path='/test' component={Sample} />
                <Sibling />
              </div>
            </BrowserRouter >
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

export default App;
```

Here is my `Sample.js`. This is like an example container that is rendering a child.

```
export default class Sample extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <span>{this.props.location.pathname}</span>
                <br />
                <Nested />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This component can display information about the current route even without the `withRouter` HOC since it is being routed to.

Here is my `Nested.js`.

```
class Nested extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <span>I am nested {this.props.location.pathname}</span>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(Nested);
```

My nested component needs the `withRouter` HOC in order to display the current route.

Finally here is my `Sibling.js`. (This is like your example where `<SearchBox />` is a sibling.)

```
class Sibling extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <span>{this.props.location.pathname}</span>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(Sibling);
```

Here all that is needed is to make sure that the sibling is nested within the router as you can see in my `App.js`, and then using the `withRouter` HOC it can display the current pathname.

To clarify: If a component can access the current pathname then it can also change the routes programmatically by doing this. `this.props.history.push(some path)`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks that clarified a lot for me!

Comment: Great. Happy to help!

Comment: Granted I am not a browserrouter expert, but I was unable to get `this.context.transitionTo` to work. Lots of `this.context.router is undefined`. Is this the new way to programmatically switch pages and `transitionTo` is deprecated. Into is a little light...